# Добавление готовой .sqlite базы данных в проект XCode

Tags: база-данных, ios, objective-c, sqlite, coredata

Имею скачанный из сети учебный проект для Xcode который демонстирует вывод данных из .sqlite в UITableView посредством Core Data. Я создал в стороннем редакторе простую базу данных, аналогичную по структуре и хочу заменить базу проекта на свою с целью теста. Но столкнулся с тем что файла самой базы нет ни в навигаторе проекта, ни в папке проекта, хотя в .xcdatamodeld таблица базы отображается. Каким образом я могу импортировать в проект свою базу и прилинковать ее к .xcdatamodeld проекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Где-то в вашем проекте должны быть строки вроде

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
    // ...
    [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[self storeURL] options:nil error:&error]
```

Где `storeURL` является путём к .sqlite-файлу базы, например:

```
- (NSURL *)storeURL {
    NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    return [applicationDocumentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
}
```

Если строки подобные описанным у вас действительно есть, то для импорта будет достаточно просто подставить файл вашей базы на место database.sqlite.